# Edge open local .html with css and js links

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with `Edge` browser (40.15063.0.0 version). I try to open local html file and have an error `XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x5, Access is denied.` for jQuery library. Does anyone have the same error?

I have css and js links to bootstrap library and some another library, which are placed in the same folder in subfolders. And all of this external resources cannot be uploaded in Edge browser. In Google Chrome all works fine.

What can be the issue of this strange behavior? Also **another developer can open this page** on his computer.

Comment: SO you are running off file protocol and not a local server/iis?

Comment: Yes, I create a local copy of report and want that user can open it and see on his local machine without internet.